# Multiple paths access a backend by traefik ingress

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I want to use traefik ingress to achieve the following functions just like nginx：

nginx config：

```
location she/admin/art/ {
    proxy_pass         http://172.18.214.174:801/admin/;
}
location he/admin/art/ {
    proxy_pass         http://172.18.214.174:801/admin/;
}
location my/admin/art/ {
    proxy_pass         http://172.18.214.174:801/admin/;
}
```

If I want to achieve this effect in the traefik ingress

I need to use  annotations:

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex: ^http://www.hx.com/she/admin/art/(.*)
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement: http://www.hx.com/admin/$1
```

Unfortunately, if I do this, I need to create three ingress just like a silly monkey

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

1. You can try to use [path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/).
2. You can also try to use [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).
3. If those would not help than you have to setup 3 different Ingress as it will not be a problem for one host.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: thanks a lot !   I am trying to use nginx ingress now. 

It can achieve my goal more simply than traefik ingress.